# use same class for data target modal in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im have a profile list page. inside the page it have modal with data-target .popupmessage. the problem is i will using the same class as much as the profile i have. how to make specific when client press the modal? because when i  click the button modal to show the modal, all the modal got show up

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <div class="profile thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">

    <button class="btn btn-yellow peopleMessage" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".popUpMessage">
      Message
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade popUpMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
  <div class="profile thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">

    <button class="btn btn-yellow peopleMessage" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".popUpMessage">
      Message
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade popUpMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

heres the example
http://www.bootply.com/95vPZK1rN8

i want to add a number at the end of .popUpMessage
so like a looping every .popUpMessage will be like this .popUpMessage1, .popUpMessage2, .popUpMessage3, .popUpMessage. but i kindly stuck.
heres the script

```
var start=1;
  var max=9999;

  for(start;start<=max;start++){
  //i stuck on the condition
}
```

Comment: Do you use the same class multiple times, just to open up the modal or does it have any other specific reason?

Comment: just to open the modal sir, if i use different class im affraid when i get more profile list, i have to create a new class for each modal

Comment: Use one modal and your own code to initialize it. Set content/title etc based on which button was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Bootstrap doesn't support multiple modals in this way. Every `data-target` property has to point out to a specific and unique modal. Else (and that's what your problem right now is), Bootstrap will simply show up all of them.

A simple approach could look like [this](http://www.bootply.com/6TjAo5GReq), by just renaming your individual `data-target` and container `class` to `popUpMessage(x, y, z)`.

That being said, you've also mentioned you're affraid of having too many classes. In this case, you may use some JavaScript magic and define your classes dynamically after loading up your page.

**EDIT:**
Since you are using Bootstrap, you can also make use of jQuery and it's `.each()` function. By doing so, you can iterate through every element (specified through your selector) and change it's attributes like `data-target` and `class`.

Take a look into [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wv8njm2m/).

Comment: i aggre with you, i plan to loop the class and add a number to the data-target and container. but i dont know the way to do that. i update my description up there. please take a look sir